# Where can I set up a cron job free of charge?

Tags: cron

I need a free web cron service that would let me setup my own crontabs that would be going to execute any URL I would have provided. The url needs to be executed every two minutes. Could you recommend any website?

Comment: I think you'll have to supply a bit (or even a lot) more information about what you are trying to achieve before you get any sensible answers.

Comment: Okay! What would you like to know?

Comment: Where the data that the job is going to manipulate is stored for a start.

Comment: On my provider's server.

Answer (score 4):

A short list (not all free, of course, and easy to find I guess) at [CronJobServices.com](http://www.cronjobservices.com/).

Comment: I never would have imagined that there was such a thing, so I never thought to look for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[OnlineCronJobs](http://onlinecronjobs.com) might be what you are looking for. It is free and supports OpenID; the only limitation is that you can only have a maximum of 5 cronjobs.

It even provides a nice [example](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/en/faq#d1) of how you might backup your database.